# Include a data file with my Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I'm creating an app that I want to seed with a data file the app will use as its initial state.  In the Eclipse project structure, where do I add the data file so that when the app is deployed to the device (and emulator) the data file is deployed with it?

Answer (score 4):

It will be helpful it you can the data file type and the purpose. If you are looking to initalize certain settings you can do it through:

Describe preferences in xml --- store in RES/XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory >
        <CheckBoxPreference  />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Load for sure onCreate():

```
/* Loading default preferences the first time application is run */
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(),
                R.xml.generalsettings, false);
```

Else,

You can hardcode data and store in the db:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE ..." + "INSERT VALUES ... INTO ... ";
db.ExecSQL(sql);
```

Else you can store this file in the Assets folder and use getAssets() to retrieve the file:

```
        getAssets().open(fileName)
```

Eg. using raw data file. In case of assets replace with above command:

```
      InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.artoodict);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String readLine = null;

    try {
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The kind of data I'm thinking about isnt user settings.  Its more like a list of locations, by state (200 - 300 locations per state).  I'm still not sure how the app will request the data; via SQLLite call, or webservice call or what.  But for now I was just gona put it in a data file (one file per state), and have the app just open the file and read the contents.

But I cant figure out where to put the data files in the eclipse project structure, and how to push the data files to the app/emulator when debugging.

Comment: And even if I was going to use SqlLite, I need to initialize the database somehow, which will require 50*200 insert statements.  So I guess my real question is how do you seed initial data required by an android app when first developing one?

Comment: Put it in the assest's folder. You can use the simple file read statements to extract the values. XML based input is another option.
See edits above

Comment: I had the same question and the answer i was looking for was in getAssets().open(FILENAME). thanks