# Importing data at initial start of application in Android?

Tags: android, import-from-csv

I need some text data (street names of a 2 million town) to get into my android application. I think the best way to do this is to store it into a sqlite database read-only when it starts the first time. As I read, doing this with a pre-defined database is pretty tedious and not clean but you have to copy it from external storage or something and have the data twice then. So I thought about using a CSV file from raw resources and delete it after import, but this is not possible too because this data will be built into the sdk file and can't be deleted any more.

My target is it to make some kind of initial data transfer from local and delete this data source. Any ideas how to achieve that properly? I'd like to go without downloading the data from a server because this would mean that the only reason my application needs an internet connection is because of downloading the initial data. Otherwise it wouldn't need an internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I know that the data I will use in my app is too complex to populate the data by hand. Moreover the app needs internet access at any rate, so I will use a Json string to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting the .csv file in you asset folder and read it.

```
       String next[] = {};
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();



   try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.csv")));
        for(;;) {
            next = reader.readNext();
            if(next != null) {
                list.add(next);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But that's the same problem with a database. You have the data twice then, when you import it into a local database on Android device. And reading the data over and over again instead of persisting it will be very slow because I need to query it in the app a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking I'd compress the data in the initial installation resource and expand it on install. This answer sees to reference a 7zip open source java api.

[Data compression on Android (other than java.util.zip ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646025/data-compression-on-android-other-than-java-util-zip)

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what exactly do you mean by "initial installation resource"?

Comment: I just meant that the archive it would be part of the initial installation. As a file included as a resource in your project. You can put it in the assets folder and use getAssets().open(filename)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602321/include-a-data-file-with-my-android-app

Comment: I'm assuming that you will be creating a database from the archive on installation.

Comment: Yes, that's the plan. But when I use assets, I have the same problem as with a csv or prebuilt database I ship with the application. I can't delete it when it is imported into the generated database, so I have all the data twice. Obviously there is no other way than using a connection to a server, because the apk is always readonly.
Another solution could be to store the data in a TreeSet, because the data has just to be readonly. I will think about it.

Comment: Yes I realize that its still a duplicate copy, I was suggesting you compress it to save space. Text will compress quite well. Good luck what ever you decide.